# how do I update useState immediately?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to add and remove items from my movies favlist but I am unable to render things immediately with `useState`. I also trying to update **favoritesFilm** in `UseEffect` but my page crashed for continuing re-render.

This is my fav component:

```
export default function FavouriteBox() {
const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProps>()
const [favoritesFilm, setFavorite] = useState<Movie[]>([])
const [isLoadingFav, setIsLoadingFav] = useState(true)
useEffect(() => {
    getFav()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(favoritesFilm)
  }, [favoritesFilm])



async function removeMovie() {
    const removed = StorageResources.storageRemove('favmovies')
    setFavorite(favoritesFilm)
  }

  async function getFav() {
    const favoriteMovies = await StorageResources.storageGet('favmovies')
    setFavorite(favoriteMovies)
    setIsLoadingFav(false)
  }
  

  const renderItemFav = ({ item }: any) => (
    <FavMovie name={item.name} title={item.title} poster_path={item.poster_path} id={item.id} />
  )
  const FavMovie = ({ title, poster_path, name, id }: any) => (
    <View style={styles.wrap}>
      <Image
        style={styles.image}
        source={{
          uri: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${poster_path}`,
        }}
      />
      {title && <Text style={styles.fav}>{title}</Text>}
      {!title && <Text style={styles.fav}>{name}</Text>}
      <MaterialCommunityIcons onPress={() => removeMovie()} name="bookmark-minus-outline" style={styles.book} />
    </View>
  )
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Preferiti</Text>
      {isLoadingFav && <LoaderBox />}
      {!isLoadingFav && (
        <FlatList
          data={favoritesFilm}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={renderItemFav}
          horizontal
        ></FlatList>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

In my home component I use this function to add to fav:

```
 const addToFavorites = async (item: Movie) => {
if (favorites.includes(item)) return null
StorageResources.storageSave('favmovies', [...favorites, item])
setFavorites([...favorites, item])
}
```

I would like to understand why it doesn't work and why every time I want to show movies in the `favmovies` component I have to refresh. (I used `AsyncStorage` for *getItem* and *removeItem*)

Comment: What you are trying to do is a default thing. You had to mess something up that it doesn't work.  This line does nothing `setFavorite(favoritesFilm)`

Comment: i update my question adding methods from async storage . 
you are right about setFavorite(favoritesFilm) but i can update the new array?

Comment: Just want to make sure if I get the question right. So you want it to render the data from your `asyncstorage` immediately instead of having empty `favoritefilms` to start with, is that right?

Comment: yes because right now the favoritesfilms render only if i refresh the page and also when i try to remove the movie from array.(i'm sorry for the bad explanation)